# iOS facebook login Without SDK Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, facebook-login

I have developed a hybrid mobile application using Sencha Touch 2. I have packaged it as iOS native application using Sencha commands.

I have to use facebook login for authentication without using Facebook mobile app / SDK. The application should launch the facebook login page / dialog and then it should come back to my app after successful login.

Please help me to fix this.

--Sridhar

Comment: were you able to accomplish it.??? i need exactly the same solution. appreciate if you can share the same with me.

Comment: It could do. I used this [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)